# I encounter this problem and my hp pavilion notebook won't start in both window 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, hp, bios, tpm

[ 0.117363] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000bb000000-0x00000000bf1fffff]), contact BIOS vendor for fixes

[

[

[

[

[

3.119436] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

3.130472] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

3.141470] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

3.151520] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

3.162473] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

3.173444] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip [ 3.184460) ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[

[ 3.195311] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip /dev/sda7: clean, 600279/2747136 files, 10446900/10985472 blocks [ 20.948143] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected

Comment: If your machine won't start on both windows & your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release; it reads like you have hardware problems which we can't help you with. You've not said what Ubuntu product, what release of that product & other details (Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices, selected by ISO at install time often), but you've given us no specifics.

Comment: Probably need to enable TPM in the BIOS.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGgSytTLK-Y

Comment: You can test your machine using *live* media; but we cannot comment on windows (*it's off-topic here*), nor your Ubuntu as we were given no specifics on what Ubuntu product/release you're asking about.  I see those messages as only *informational* (TPM) & have normal booting anyway. The *fsck* message is probably user *procedure* created (eg. using power button to turn off!)